# Curl. Ошибка при отправке на сервер

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Отправляю с помощью curl данные в ответ получаю:

```
"Произошла ошибка при обработке запроса"
```

Заголовки приходят следующие:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=windows-1251
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< jsonerror: true
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 25 Jan 2016 14:06:57 GMT
< Content-Length: 122
< 
* Connection #0 to host ati.su left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Что значит `jsonerror: true` В чем может быть проблема? Из-за чего не могу достучаться до сервера?

Answer (score 1):

`jsonerror: true` – это кастомный заголовок, который отдает сервер.

500 ошибка, это ошибка сервера, а не вашего запроса. То есть на хосте `ati.su` по вашему запросу сервер "падает".

Рекомендую изучить протокол `HTTP`, что бы не было таких "глупых" вопросов. Как минимум статусы `HTTP` – [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

Могу только предположить, используя телепатические возможности, что в своем запросе вы передаете в параметрах некорректный json. Либо вообще не передаете параметры, хотя обязаны.

Т.е. без полного кода и документации к данному сервису - тут не разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в кодировке скрипта. 
Php-скрипт нужно было сделать в кодировку utf-8. Всем спасибо.